# Group Policy Application Install Windows 10

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-10

When trying to install a program from group policy on Windows 10 I am receiving an error in event viewer.

"The assignment of application failed. The error was: %%65"

I have found similar posts (although the error # was different) that suggested changing "Startup policy processing wait time". After doing so I am still receiving this error.

This is only happening on our Windows 10 machines.

Has anyone ran into this and have a solution?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Can be caused by a few things, here's the usual primer:
[Group Policy installation failed error 1274](https://serverfault.com/questions/44257/group-policy-installation-failed-error-1274)

Some other causes:
Spanning Tree on the network switch causes the port to be Blocked for a few seconds while the switch determines if there is a loop. I'm having a similar issue:
[Group Policy Application on Boot with MSTP & really really fast computers](https://serverfault.com/questions/758547/group-policy-application-on-boot-with-mstp-really-really-fast-computers)

Also, I saw something about UNC hardening causing Win 10 to have difficulties accessing the NETLOGON UNC on boot, but you'd need to do additional research.